# Qt widget goes behind the taskbar. How to keep it above?

Tags: qt

I’ve an issue that my application window goes behind the taskbar of my PC. I use win 8. same issue i found when i use in an android device also.

The same issue is found to be discussed in a link [screen-area](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/qt-dev-screen-area/)

I tried the same.. but it is visible to user that the widget resize after show. Is there a better way to resolve this?